# How to correct "from...to...to" here?

Tags: grammar

I am applying for a Ph.D. program. I am writing Statement of Purpose and Objectives. So in the first sentence, I want to introduce my education background. My first sentence is:

> As a highly motivated student with a strong multidisciplinary
> background, with degrees **from journalism to economics to mathematics
> and statistics**, with over five years of academic experience in
> research, analyzing public and private data, and running statistical
> analysis, I am confident that I would be a successful Ph.D. student
> and researcher in the biostatistics field.

I know from...to...to is wrong here. But how to change?

Comment: I'm not convinced that it *is* wrong!  But you didn't tell us what you actually want to say, so it's hard to know how to "correct" it.  Do you actually have three or four undergraduate degrees?!

Comment: And were the disciplines you mention all degree majors or honours degrees or master's degrees.. You need to be much more specific, as stangdon says.

Comment: @stangdon What I want to say is my breadth of knowledge. My undergraduate degree is journalism. I have 3 masters: 2 econ,  1 math and stats. So that's why I am using from...to...to... here.

Comment: Be elegant, be simpler: with degrees in journalism, economics, mathematics and statistics. It's fine not to specify graduate/undergraduate at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's common in marketing language, I would avoid the construction *from...to* for discrete items that can't be thought of as points on a line or spectrum.

You don't mention how many degrees you hold, but if it's no more than the four you mention you'd probably be best off simply listing them:

> As a highly motivated student with a strong multidisciplinary background, **with degrees in** journalism, economics, mathematics and statistics...

If you hold an exceptionally large number of degrees, a list of which would break the flow of the sentence, you could give an abridged list:

> As a highly motivated student with a strong multidisciplinary background, **with degrees including** journalism, economics, mathematics and statistics...

Comment: I really appreciate your help!